# How can I replace Kendo UI ComboBoxFor control with relevant MVC control

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

For some reason I need to replace one of `Kendo` UI Control with that of MVC control. Below is my `Kendo` control in `Index.cshtml` file

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ProductId)
  .Name("GreenProduct")
  .DataTextField("Name")
  .DataValueField("ProductId")
  .AutoBind(false)
  .DataSource(datasource => datasource
  .Read(read => read
       .Action("GetProductForProject", "Product")
       .Data("hierarchy.filterProduct")
       .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
        )
       .ServerFiltering(true)
        )
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
  .Suggest(false)
  .Delay(0)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
  )
```

This is how I tried

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(here data,  new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

But there is no datasource available. Do I need to make API call in Index Action methond ? How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it  send request to the endpoints and bind the options with the response data with js codes

I tried as below in my view:

```
@{   
    var select = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "SelectOne" } };
}

@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDown",select)

<script>
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://localhost:44309/Home/GetEntity', true);
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
            var json = httpRequest.responseText;
            var arr = JSON.parse(json);
            console.log(arr)
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                var drop = document.getElementById("MyDropDown")                
                var op = document.createElement("option");
                op.value = arr[i].id;
                op.innerHTML=arr[i].name
                drop.appendChild(op)
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

The endpoint/entity:

```
public IActionResult GetEntity()
        {
            var someentity = new List<SomeEntity>() { new SomeEntity() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" }, new SomeEntity() { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" } };
            return Ok(someentity);
        }
```

The result:

[image]